# Преобразование строки в кортеж по разделителю

Tags: python

Есть строка вида:

```
numbers = '68259640,86902941,41040730,86376448,59169047,77037959,80441051,83822347,90871250,90672483,89596230,88062037,86575434,84129427,76139274,74980634,65350893,60685291,55771316'
```

Нужно ее преобразовать в кортеж вида:

```
(68259640,86902941,41040730,86376448,59169047,77037959,80441051,83822347,90871250,90672483,89596230,88062037,86575434,84129427,76139274,74980634,65350893,60685291,55771316)
```

Не подскажете как? Чтобы по индексу например `1` я получил значение `86902941`

Comment: еще так можно eval(numbers)

Comment: @vadimvaduxa очень опасная функция, про которую стоит просто забыть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разбить с помощью метода `.split()` (получится список строк), потом через генератор преобразовать строки в `int`, потом уже превратить все в кортеж:

```
s = '68259640,86902941,41040730,86376448,59169047,77037959,80441051,83822347,90871250,90672483,89596230,88062037,86575434,84129427,76139274,74980634,65350893,60685291,55771316'

t = tuple(int(item) for item in s.split(','))
print(t)
# (68259640, 86902941, 41040730, 86376448, 59169047, 77037959, 80441051, 83822347, 90871250, 90672483, 89596230, 88062037, 86575434, 84129427, 76139274, 74980634, 65350893, 60685291, 55771316)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
t = tuple(map(int, s.split(',')))
# t == (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```